# \begin{Center} from ragged2e introduces excessive spacing in math mode

Tags: environments, center, ragged2e

I've tried to find this asked somewhere before, however I was unable.

I use the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[a5paper, total={4.1in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{eulerpx}
\usepackage[cal=zapfc, calscaled=1.2, scr=euler, frak=euler, bb=px]{mathalpha}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
```

The reagged2e package provides the Center environment (not the 'center' environment). This is a good fit for some of my purposes. I've (very quickly) though encountered the following problem: the Center environment ruins use of the math environment wrt. e.g. the `\in` symbol. The first of the below pictures show without Center environment, and the second shows with the Center environment.
[image]
The code employed is shown here:

```
\begin{equation*}
m \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
\begin{Center}
$m\in \mathbb{R}$
\end{Center}
```

I believe, that this is because of some break-like property of the Center environment, however I'm unsure (and can't check, as I don't know how). I'd like to still use the environment, but this is brutal. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I've been told (by [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif)) the preamble plus code can be reduced to:

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
m \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
\begin{Center}
$m\in \mathbb{R}$
\end{Center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't separate preamble and code, post the MWE as one single document. That is much easier to copy and test.

Comment: Note that the preamble can be reduced to `ragged2e,amsmath,amssymb`. I agree it seems `Center` might set some excessive values

Comment: I would probably rephrase the title of your question to `\begin{Center} from ragged2e introduces excessive spacing in math mode` as it better suits the problem

Comment: @daleif I've updated the document. Thanks for the help, I'll try to follow the stylistic guidelines and make better titles:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not related to math really. The `Center` environment only allows a finite stretch at the margins so *any* short line whether text or math will be underfull and any stretchable space within the line will be over stretched.

Within the scope of Center you can remove the stretch from math spaces by multiplying by 1.  Both these lines are underfull but now the over-stretching just happens at the margin. The package already does a similar change to inter-word spacing so that it does not stretch, even when th eline is underfull.

Or you could use `center` which works better here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{Center}\medmuskip=1\medmuskip \thickmuskip=1\thickmuskip \thinmuskip=1\thinmuskip
  hello world

  $m\in \mathbf{R}$
\end{Center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works wonders for my purposes. I'm interested in still using the Center environment, as it automatically split words at the ends of each line if necessary (and center I believe doesn't).
I know this is maybe an unreasonable ask, but does this lead to other spacing problems (or environment problems for that matter), or can I accept this as the answer?

Comment: @studyingmathematics as I say the environment already does this (removing stretch) for text spaces, it just doesn't do it for math o doing that (within the scope of center, or redefining Center to always do that) are fine.

Comment: @studyingmathematics  But really the ragged2e environments for text or math do not really work for one line  input, they only allow 4em or so extra space (so hyphenation works) so if you have a short line that can not reach that you are doomed. RaggedRight is OK as like  a standard paragraph the final line has `\parfillskip` but `Center` makes no adjustment for the lsat (or only) line and so will always be badness 10000 underfull if the line is not nearly full.

Comment: This was useful context to me, as I'm not very aquatinted with Latex terminology (and this felt a bit more accessible). I'll accept this as the answer, and thank you for your help:)